# Horizontal space on display:table justified bootstrap navbar on Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari

On Desktop and iOS versions of Safari -- a mysterious horizontal space is being added to both sides of a justified bootstrap 3 navbar menu.

What can I do to remove the spacing?

Firefox, Chrome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

**JSFiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/Lscerkzx/1/**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    table-layout: auto;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0;
}
li {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I've also tried to use '**table-layout: fixed**' which seems to work in some cases. But I don't want to use it if possible.

**JSFiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/Lscerkzx/2/**

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
/*      table-layout: auto; */
    table-layout: fixed;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; //added
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some styling being applied to the `:before` on the nav. If you add this your problem should be fixed!

```
.nav:before {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: looks like working, huge thanks! -- and would need to do .nav:after as well of course --> https://jsfiddle.net/Lscerkzx/3/

Comment: Yup, now you're cooking :)